# NullPointer: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.ar.core.Session com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.getSession()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, fragment, arcore, fragmentmanager

I am trying to add an ArFragment into a FrameLayout at runtime

Getting this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'com.google.ar.core.Session com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.getSession()' on a null object reference
```

This is my code in MainActivity.java

```
  ItemOneFragment  fragment = new ItemOneFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        ft.commit();
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/boundingBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

ItemOneFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;

public class ItemOneFragment extends ArFragment {

    public static ItemOneFragment newInstance() {
        ItemOneFragment fragment = new ItemOneFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

In ItemOnFragment.java, if I change from `extends ArFragment` to `extends Fragment`, it works perfectly fine. Why I am getting error for ArFragment?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Sceneform and since you're extending from `ArFragment` you need to let its base class, `BaseArFragment`, create its View which will initialize its `arSceneView` property. Remove your `onCreateView()` function and let the base class do it.

For reference, here's `BaseArFragment`:
https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/sceneformux/ux/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/BaseArFragment.java#L163

BTW, Google open sourced and deprecated Sceneform some months ago.